# What is the inverse of this function?

Tags: haskell

```
flattern :: [(Char, Int)] -> String
flattern [] = ""
flattern ((w,l):xs) = show l ++ w : flattern xs
```

What would be the inverse function of this? Is there any way of be able to work this out?

Comment: Not knowing Haskell really, I don't think there is a inverse function for this (in the strict sense of inverse).

Comment: Why is this tagged with "work"? What work application could there possibly be to this cryptic and horribly titled question?

Answer (score 2):

It's not invertible:

1. There are strings that cannot be reproduced by this function (any string not starting with a digit).
2. It's not even partially invertible.  There are also strings that correspond to multiple inputs: `"1111"` can be produced by either `[('1',1),('1',1)]` or `[('1',111)]`.

Are you sure that this was the function to invert, and not something like `flattern ((w,l):xs) = replicate l w ++ flattern xs`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want, you could parse the output of the function to try and reconstruct what the arguments must have been.

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

unflat1 :: Parser (Char, Int)
unflat1 = do
           c <- anyChar
           n <- many1 digit
           return (c, read n) 

readExpr :: String -> Either String [(Char, Int)]
readExpr input = case parse (many unflat1) "unflat" input of
    Left err -> Left ("No match: " ++ show err)
    Right val -> Right val
```

This sorta works, as long as flattern does not have numbers as the first input.
Something like `flattern [('a',1), ('2',3)]` will be parsed as `[(a, 123)]`.